# Categorical covariate with two way anova in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova, ancova, rstatix

This is a random sample of my data set:

```
structure(list(DTI_ID = structure(c(31L, 241L, 84L, 298L, 185L, 
269L, 198L, 24L, 286L, 177L, 228L, 158L, 57L, 293L, 218L, 8L, 
180L, 39L, 211L, 134L, 291L, 309L, 99L, 70L, 154L, 138L, 250L, 
41L, 276L, 262L, 96L, 139L, 232L, 12L, 294L, 38L, 244L, 289L, 
280L, 196L, 58L, 44L, 188L, 152L, 143L, 302L, 201L, 27L, 24L, 
67L, 247L, 223L, 74L, 32L, 110L, 98L, 303L, 256L, 71L, 30L, 236L, 
266L, 307L, 224L, 100L, 73L, 288L, 230L, 182L, 159L, 190L, 123L, 
241L, 169L, 103L, 40L, 248L, 293L, 60L, 260L, 168L, 267L, 144L, 
89L, 139L, 231L, 204L, 130L, 278L, 227L, 205L, 268L, 88L, 221L, 
208L, 306L, 242L, 145L, 21L, 165L, 217L, 159L, 206L, 70L, 121L, 
181L, 95L, 279L, 265L, 4L, 122L, 177L, 234L, 34L, 261L, 86L, 
2L, 296L, 39L, 283L, 251L, 126L, 188L, 176L, 220L, 77L, 225L, 
73L, 48L, 107L, 280L, 118L, 38L, 310L, 297L, 258L, 89L, 205L, 
4L, 54L, 16L, 95L, 119L, 40L, 9L, 66L, 64L, 55L, 131L, 290L, 
166L, 170L, 182L, 139L, 125L, 201L, 302L, 137L, 8L, 81L, 61L, 
119L, 278L, 135L, 117L, 65L, 21L, 200L, 150L, 146L, 54L, 262L, 
152L, 224L, 162L, 111L, 251L, 130L, 41L, 271L, 33L, 86L, 32L, 
199L, 49L, 180L, 101L, 271L, 80L, 84L, 293L, 5L, 170L, 74L, 279L, 
281L, 255L, 210L, 52L, 248L, 53L, 121L, 190L, 141L, 213L, 138L, 
112L, 234L, 235L, 40L, 233L, 115L, 154L, 11L, 76L, 29L, 19L, 
249L, 1L, 207L), .Label = c("5356", "5357", "5358", "5359", "5360", 
"5363", "5373", "5381", "5383", "5386", "5395", "5397", "5400", 
"5401", "5444", "5445", "5446", "5448", "5450", "5451", "5454", 
"5472", "5473", "5475", "5476", "5477", "5478", "5480", "5481", 
"5483", "5487", "5494", "5495", "5504", "5505", "5506", "5507", 
"5508", "5509", "5513", "5514", "5515", "5516", "5517", "5518", 
"5519", "5521", "5523", "5524", "5526", "5527", "5528", "5544", 
"5545", "5546", "5547", "5551", "5552", "5553", "5554", "5555", 
"5558", "5559", "5560", "5562", "5564", "5566", "5573", "5574", 
"5575", "5576", "5577", "5578", "5579", "5584", "5585", "5587", 
"5588", "5589", "5591", "5594", "5595", "5604", "5611", "5612", 
"5613", "5615", "5616", "5619", "5620", "5621", "5622", "5626", 
"5627", "5628", "5631", "5632", "5634", "5635", "5643", "5652", 
"5653", "5654", "5655", "5656", "5657", "5659", "5660", "5661", 
"5664", "5665", "5666", "5669", "5671", "5672", "5673", "5678", 
"5680", "5688", "5689", "5690", "5691", "5692", "5698", "5699", 
"5700", "5702", "5703", "5704", "5706", "5708", "5709", "5710", 
"5730", "5731", "5732", "5733", "5734", "5735", "5739", "5740", 
"5741", "5742", "5743", "5744", "5745", "5746", "5747", "5748", 
"5749", "5750", "5753", "5754", "5755", "5766", "5767", "5776", 
"5777", "5778", "5779", "5780", "5781", "5787", "5788", "5789", 
"5790", "5791", "5792", "5793", "5797", "5798", "5799", "5800", 
"5801", "5810", "5811", "5812", "5813", "5814", "5819", "5820", 
"5821", "5822", "5823", "5824", "5825", "5827", "5828", "5829", 
"5830", "5857", "5859", "5874", "5875", "5876", "5877", "5878", 
"5879", "5883", "5884", "5886", "5887", "5888", "5889", "5890", 
"5892", "5893", "5896", "5899", "5900", "5909", "5910", "5918", 
"5919", "5920", "5921", "5922", "5923", "5927", "5929", "5931", 
"5932", "5933", "5934", "5936", "5937", "5941", "5943", "5944", 
"5949", "5950", "5951", "5952", "5956", "5957", "5958", "5959", 
"5971", "5972", "5973", "5976", "5979", "5980", "5981", "6001", 
"6002", "6003", "6004", "6005", "6009", "6027", "6028", "6033", 
"6042", "6054", "6063", "6067", "6073", "6076", "6077", "6078", 
"6079", "6080", "6081", "6082", "6083", "6098", "6102", "6103", 
"6104", "6105", "6106", "6107", "6111", "6119", "6133", "6146", 
"6147", "6157", "6158", "6160", "6161", "6162", "6163", "6164", 
"6165", "6166", "6167", "6168", "6169", "6170", "6171", "6172", 
"6173", "6174", "6175", "6190", "6193", "6195", "6196", "6197", 
"6208", "6228", "6229", "6232", "6255", "6268", "6269", "6270", 
"6275"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"
), class = "factor"), Age = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Young", "Old"), class = "factor"), 
    ROI = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("A", "B","C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.326713741, 0.349206239, 0.365954667, 
    0.313958377, 0.480487555, 0.431199849, 0.446729183, 0.337009728, 
    0.331222087, 0.386937141, 0.372758657, 0.305083066, 0.504718482, 
    0.414191663, 0.40949735, 0.271525055, 0.30009532, 0.50117749, 
    0.387669057, 0.330797315, 0.390679717, 0.452181876, 0.423188657, 
    0.396808296, 0.388510793, 0.298505336, 0.412985921, 0.327000797, 
    0.304242313, 0.277513236, 0.394773901, 0.4322685, 0.440891623, 
    0.439061254, 0.453015536, 0.385896087, 0.452299237, 0.296923041, 
    0.443324417, 0.420699686, 0.282610774, 0.303566545, 0.535346806, 
    0.393591255, 0.32561186, 0.309230596, 0.417596817, 0.281766504, 
    0.445347071, 0.353419632, 0.354420125, 0.429613769, 0.385733992, 
    0.155136898, 0.485385537, 0.439544022, 0.436584443, 0.458706915, 
    0.600399196, 0.440390527, 0.362952292, 0.37253055, 0.37306264, 
    0.371298164, 0.469741255, 0.573943496, 0.283266962, 0.391182601, 
    0.663566113, 0.517713368, 0.327498972, 0.353969425, 0.443648636, 
    0.449972481, 0.434426159, 0.305042148, 0.422493547, 0.194572225, 
    0.331083208, 0.418288261, 0.447215647, 0.429001331, 0.339149892, 
    0.336879104, 0.471237898, 0.408330619, 0.393405557, 0.486086488, 
    0.427713692, 0.379242182, 0.40456596, 0.326695889, 0.393235713, 
    0.452374548, 0.332855165, 0.323469192, 0.396484613, 0.372199923, 
    0.257353246, 0.405249774, 0.326494843, 0.420468688, 0.335335255, 
    0.267627925, 0.379383296, 0.338241786, 0.416064918, 0.381003618, 
    0.284006208, 0.442705005, 0.494199812, 0.464447916, 0.370418996, 
    0.293953657, 0.34482345, 0.47208631, 0.378798842, 0.407261223, 
    0.34767586, 0.424341202, 0.434532404, 0.342623293, 0.628901243, 
    0.381492049, 0.540111601, 0.392371207, 0.459349483, 0.373172134, 
    0.270272404, 0.413454324, 0.375994682, 0.470298111, 0.340463549, 
    0.31613645, 0.470312864, 0.410651028, 0.276164204, 0.341546267, 
    0.402167588, 0.465735435, 0.434102625, 0.328114063, 0.394582212, 
    0.331681252, 0.387562275, 0.3989245, 0.44939962, 0.29586333, 
    0.398924828, 0.559520543, 0.392099082, 0.589552164, 0.397368163, 
    0.375135392, 0.348508835, 0.447002649, 0.407775551, 0.404435992, 
    0.666776299, 0.265039146, 0.25311482, 0.354386091, 0.44051528, 
    0.416727781, 0.460624784, 0.455415428, 0.445090771, 0.502343714, 
    0.393426061, 0.463244319, 0.345586747, 0.291874498, 0.564393103, 
    0.400276631, 0.41512531, 0.308440536, 0.373545259, 0.272377819, 
    0.434890926, 0.358394623, 0.414819628, 0.761894882, 0.409700364, 
    0.403811544, 0.469092041, 0.397044837, 0.312479883, 0.294876397, 
    0.314414322, 0.428720832, 0.329074681, 0.311423391, 0.444689006, 
    0.254723012, 0.248710752, 0.270434052, 0.416304022, 0.38875562, 
    0.396840513, 0.296386898, 0.454476953, 0.474986047, 0.427072734, 
    0.270839244, 0.426266223, 0.586857438, 0.348018169, 0.386638522, 
    0.349321723, 0.418692261, 0.295630395, 0.463439822, 0.286190838, 
    0.336389571, 0.422766507, 0.231764346, 0.358636618, 0.562871873, 
    0.381515294, 0.28637746)), row.names = c(961L, 1171L, 84L, 
608L, 805L, 889L, 818L, 334L, 596L, 177L, 848L, 468L, 987L, 293L, 
218L, 318L, 1110L, 969L, 211L, 1064L, 1221L, 1239L, 99L, 70L, 
1084L, 448L, 250L, 351L, 586L, 572L, 1026L, 139L, 232L, 632L, 
914L, 658L, 1174L, 909L, 280L, 1126L, 368L, 354L, 808L, 1082L, 
453L, 612L, 201L, 337L, 644L, 67L, 1177L, 1153L, 694L, 962L, 
1040L, 98L, 923L, 1186L, 691L, 650L, 236L, 886L, 307L, 224L, 
100L, 1003L, 598L, 230L, 1112L, 779L, 500L, 433L, 861L, 1099L, 
103L, 350L, 248L, 1223L, 370L, 260L, 788L, 267L, 454L, 399L, 
1069L, 231L, 204L, 1060L, 1208L, 847L, 205L, 578L, 88L, 221L, 
518L, 616L, 242L, 1075L, 951L, 165L, 527L, 1089L, 206L, 380L, 
431L, 801L, 1025L, 279L, 575L, 624L, 1052L, 1107L, 854L, 344L, 
1191L, 86L, 2L, 916L, 659L, 903L, 251L, 436L, 1118L, 796L, 1150L, 
77L, 1155L, 693L, 358L, 107L, 1210L, 1048L, 968L, 620L, 1227L, 
258L, 1019L, 515L, 4L, 674L, 16L, 405L, 739L, 660L, 629L, 66L, 
64L, 365L, 1061L, 1220L, 166L, 1100L, 182L, 759L, 745L, 1131L, 
302L, 757L, 938L, 391L, 371L, 119L, 278L, 135L, 117L, 995L, 21L, 
1130L, 150L, 1076L, 364L, 1192L, 772L, 844L, 782L, 421L, 561L, 
440L, 41L, 1201L, 963L, 706L, 652L, 1129L, 669L, 180L, 1031L, 
581L, 390L, 704L, 603L, 625L, 170L, 384L, 899L, 591L, 255L, 830L, 
672L, 558L, 983L, 121L, 190L, 451L, 213L, 1068L, 1042L, 234L, 
545L, 40L, 543L, 1045L, 464L, 941L, 76L, 959L, 329L, 1179L, 621L, 
517L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   DTI_ID Gender Age   ROI              value
   <fct>  <fct>  <fct> <fct>            <dbl>
 1 5927   Male   Old   A                 0.395
 2 5634   Male   Old   C                 0.433
 3 5547   Female Old   B                 0.257
 4 5979   Male   Old   C                 0.404
 5 5660   Male   Old   A                 0.398
 6 5876   Female Old   D                 0.426
 7 5518   Male   Old   A                 0.404
 8 6001   Female Old   D                 0.392
 9 6042   Male   Old   A                 0.388
10 5821   Male   Old   A                 0.344
```

`ROI` is a region of interest within each subject, so all subjects have all 4 ROIs.

I would like to calculate a 2-way ANCOVA 4(ROIs [a/b/c/d] - within) x 2 (Age [young/old] - between) + Gender [covariate] to determine the interaction effects of `age` and `ROI` on `value`, controlling for `Gender`.

To do that, I calculated:

```
#2-way ANOVA
res.aov2 <- df %>% 
  anova_test(value ~ Gender + Age*ROI, within = ROI, wid= DTI_ID)
get_anova_table(res.aov2)
```

which works fine and outputs:

```
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

   Effect DFn  DFd       F         p p<.05      ges
1  Gender   1 1227   5.196  2.30e-02     * 0.004000
2     Age   1 1227   0.732  3.92e-01       0.000596
3     ROI   3 1227 228.933 6.13e-118     * 0.359000
4 Age:ROI   3 1227  22.258  4.90e-14     * 0.052000
```

I then want to run a multiple comparisons to generate p values that I can graph over boxplots for visualization of the analyses.

I am using `emmeans_test`:

```
# Pairwise comparisons
pwc2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ROI) %>%
  emmeans_test(value ~ Age, covariate = Gender,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

but receive the error:

```
Error in contrast.emmGrid(res.emmeans, by = grouping.vars, method = method, : Nonconforming number of contrast coefficients
```

I cannot figure out why, as the pairwise comparison works fine when I remove the covariate.  Does it have to do with a categorical variable being used as a covariate? I am stuck and want to make sure I am reporting the appropriate p-values in my chart.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to try [`multcomp::glht`](https://stat.ethz.ch/~meier/teaching/anova/contrasts-and-multiple-testing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Gender` to group_by as well, allowed the code to run properly.